# React Native - Flatlist makes statusBar and bottom bar gone

Tags: react-native

I have a FlatList in my Chat Screen but I notice that in Android, the statusbar and bottombar is gone.
Here is the original code and screenshot.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <...otherComponent/>
     <FlatList
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        data={messages}
        renderItem={_renderList}             
</SafeAreaView>
```

[image]

If I remove `FlatList`, the statusbar and bottombar will appear again.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <...otherComponent/>         
</SafeAreaView>
```

[image]

**I want the statusbar and bottombar to be shown.** Any idea what props should be pass into `FlatList`? or wrap with any other component?

Comment: Try to add `style={{flex: 1}}` prop to your `FlatList` Component.

Comment: I tried, no luck still the same :(

Comment: Try to add `Flatlist` within another View and give that `View style={{flex: 1}}` prop.

Comment: I think there is some issue on my Image/Video type message. Just now I tried to populate the Flatlist again, it works fine lol. 
Will dive deep into Image/VIdeo type message that contained by the Flatlist